# wacom tablet right mouse and 3D cursor

Tags: 3d-cursor

just got a new wacom tablet , mapped 
 the right mouse button 
for selecting ,everything great  but how can i  get rid of the 3D cursor,wich is following my pointer the all time ???
(disabling it in user- pref just left it frozen in the middle ...)

---

unfortunatly after installing window 10 , reinstalling the driver , the stylus is not selcting with RM button , just get a variation of usless ripple effect at the cursor and it does not select anymore...

Comment: disable continuous grab in the system preferences.

Answer (score 6):

I've been using a wacom tablet for a long time. What works for me is mapping the tip to click, the lower button for right click, top button to double click. Then I enable Emulate 3 Button mouse.

[image]

- To zoom in I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd> while pressing/draggin the pen
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> Drag to rotate
- <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd> Drag to move siedeways and up/down
- Selecting I do by hovering over the vertices/edges/faces and clicking on the lower button

*I like this configuration because Continuous grab lets me select and grab in a single operation.*

Comment: well , i have exactly this setting and the 3D cursor is still following my pointer wherever  i select...

Comment: well thanks + i had to map in Blender Pref the 3Dcursor to "doubleclick" so it's not in the way anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Blender *Preferences> Input> Tablet> Tablet API* set it to *Windows Ink*.